# Android sqlite execute multiple queries on json read

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I'm reading a web service that returns a JSON, parse and write into a SQLite Database in Android. The process is very slow because I have to do each insertion separately.

I do this process in background

Is there a way to improve this process?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do batch inserts.

Pseudocode:

```
db.beginTransaction();
for (entry : listOfEntries) {
    db.insert(entry);
}

db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

That increased the speed of inserts extremely.

If it doesn't work check out this post about [faster insertions](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/)

Comment: This works!!! you have reason, it's very fast. Go from 1 minute 56 seconds to 3 SECONDS!!! Thank you!!!